# Twilio HTTP Post processing in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, http-post, twilio

I want to get Twilio recording into AWS S3 with a Lambda function and thought it'd be simpler with lots of examples, but I'm still trying to figure it out.

Once recording is available Twilio sends HTTP POST with content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I have verified that Lambda is receiving this HTTP POST.

I now want to use Lambda function to extract "RecordingUrl=https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/...." from the body of the POST and download the file at that URL to an S3 bucket.

Any pointers to get started would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Twilio Function in this blog (under the sub-heading, Creating the Function), and see if that provides the functionality you are looking for in a slightly different way.

[Encrypting and Storing Twilio Flex Recordings Off-site](https://www.twilio.com/blog/encrypt-store-twilio-flex-recordings-site)

Comment: Thank you and I will read up and/or try it later today.  I still think that there should be plenty of examples of how to parse the HTTP POST as per my original question so hoping someone here will jump in with tips.